# How to clear Cefsharp (Chromium) proxy cache to change proxy credentials?

Tags: c#, chromium, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

In my C# Cefsharp Application I connect to a proxy with username/password.

The IRequestHandler calls GetAuthCredentials() only once when the proxy asks for authentification, it seems they are cached then. so once the credentials are set can I trigger it again somehow to change the credentials?

How can I change the proxy credentials during runtime?

Thanks a lot

```
public bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
{
    if (isProxy != true)
    {
        callback.Continue(Program.user.getEmailAddress(),
        Program.user.getPassword());
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: See https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16259

Comment: Thanks, so strange it's impossible. They write "I suggest using a different form of authentication where your application can manage login/logout" - Is there another way to connect to a proxy in cefsharp?

Comment: It's unusual that a proxy would change it's username/password within an applications lifespan. It's a `CEF` limitation, not a `CefSharp` one. For background please read the first few paragraphs of https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation and https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#proxy-resolution

Comment: The proxy provider we are working on is changing its proxies IPs depending on the username. Within a runtime we need to use multiple IPs to detect how a websites behaviour changes with a different IP. Does that mean it's impossible without running another instance for each IP or restarting the application?

Comment: You can change the proxy at runtime as linked above,  this should hopefully trigger a new credentials request.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? One workaround I found was to edit my host file to have a list of made up domains all of which point to the actual proxy IP, so CEF treat them as different, but this tends to fail as the proxy provider changes IPs randomly.